# Beachvolleyball: When can you block an opponent beyond the net?

Tags: rules, volleyball, beach-volleyball

In beachvolleyball, the rules about blocking a ball beyond the net and what is considered an attack hit are a bit unclear to me. Here are the relevant rules: (from  https://www.fivb.com/en/beachvolleyball/thegame_bvb_glossary/officialrulesofthegames )

> 11.1 REACHING BEYOND THE NET
>
> 11.1.1 In blocking, a player may touch the ball beyond the net, provided that he/she does not interfere with the opponent’s play, before the latter’s attack hit.
>
> [...]
>
> 13.1 CHARACTERISTICS OF THE ATTACK HIT
>
> 13.1.1 All actions which direct the ball towards the opponent, with the exception of service and block, are considered as attack hits.

Lets say player A sets player B, and player C (other team) is getting ready to block B. Do I understand the rules correctly in the following scenarios?

1. Player A sets perpendicular to the net and the ball clearly stays on their teams side.
   Therefore it is not an attack hit, and player C may not touch the ball before B because it would interfere with B's play.
2. Player A sets the ball such that it is moving towards the net and might go over if neither B or C touch it, but it is in reach of both B and C. Because A already made an attack hit, C may hit it before B, even tough it interferes with B's play.
3. Player A sets the ball such that it is moving towards the net but does not seem likely to go over. Both player B and C are in reach of it. Because the set is not going over, it is not an attack hit and player C may not touch it before player B *(im very unsure here)*.
4. Player A sets in such a way that the ball stays on their side but B is is not able to reach it. C may hit it because it is not interfering with B's play.

Do I get this correctly? Generally I am not sure if I understand 13.1.1 correctly.  "All actions which direct the ball towards the opponent" -> does the ball have to actually be on a trajectory to the opponents side to count as an attack hit, or is it enough that it goes into the direction of the opponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Player A sets perpendicular to the net and the ball clearly stays on their teams side. Therefore it is not an attack hit, and player C may not touch the ball before B because it would interfere with B's play.

Correct.

> Player A sets the ball such that it is moving towards the net and might go over if neither B or C touch it, but it is in reach of both B and C. Because A already made an attack hit, C may hit it before B, even tough it interferes with B's play.

No; the restriction on "no interference" takes precedence here. You can perhaps argue that the wording of the rules isn't entirely precise here, but this is the way the game works.

> Player A sets the ball such that it is moving towards the net but does not seem likely to go over. Both player B and C are in reach of it. Because the set is not going over, it is not an attack hit and player C may not touch it before player B

Correct, this is not an attack hit - the ball must be actually going to pass over the net for it to be an attack hit.

> Player A sets in such a way that the ball stays on their side but B is is not able to reach it. C may hit it because it is not interfering with B's play.

This is not an attack hit so blocking is not allowed. But in any case, if C isn't able to reach the ball B should just keep well out of the way and win the point anyway.